# How to perform user-locking in Spring-MVC?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I wanted to know how I can perform user locking (or the best way to perform the same) i.e. if a user is already logged in from a device and tries to login from another device, he/she should be notified that a session is already available for that user and an option to close other session and start a new one.

Framework Used Spring-MVC + hibernate 4.1.

And one more thing: how can I set a list of some user hashmap object in application context?

Answer (score 2):

That can be done with Spring Security and [Conncurrent Session Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-sessions). You can define how many sessions may exist concurrently and decide what to do if the maximum exceeds.

Comment: is there any other basic method? i mean without using spring security.

Comment: You may write your own one, by using an [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) that detects if sessions are created.

Comment: can you give an example for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Their is a simple xml configuration in spring security for the same. First you have to register the SessionRegistry bean. I have used default class of SessionRegistryImpl of spring security for Session registry like :

```
<bean id="sessionRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

After that we have to register the ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy with container and tell it the maximum session allowed per user.
 Example:

```
<bean id="sessionStrategy"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
    <property name="maximumSessions"
        value="${security.config.sessionStrategy.maximumSessions.value}" />
    <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true" />
</bean>
```

`security.config.sessionStrategy.maximumSessions.value` is the integer value specified in property file. By varying the maximumSessions property value we can define maximum concurrent users easily.