# Not able to set Object (HashMap) at application level

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I wanted to set a Hashmap object (of logged in users)  at application level. But unable to do the same as with every request my old user list saved in Hashmap object is getting refreshed and returning only current logged in user.
I have tried many example but no luck.
Below is my code

```
<bean id="applicationContextProvder" class="com.starter.basic.ApplicationContextProvider"/>

<bean id="testBean" class="com.starter.basic.TestBean"/>


TestBean tb = appContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("testBean", TestBean.class)
```

```
    public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware
     {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac)
            throws BeansException {
        context = ac;
    }
  }
```

```
public class TestBean implements ServletContextAware {
    private HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<String ,String >();

 }

  public HashMap getUsers(){
           return hashMap;
   }
```

Framework used Spring MVC 3 + Hibernate 4.0

If anyone not able to understand my points above. What i am trying to do is if some user is already logged in and try to login again from another device user should blocked. I should get that user from Hashmap object on his second login. I could do this from back end flag. But my requirement is to use application context.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739582/how-to-perform-user-locking-in-spring-mvc/31739662#31739662

Comment: Is this a typing mistake that your method `getUsers` is actually outside the class TestBean scope?

Comment: My code is correct it was just a typing mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need ***Singleton Pattern*** for your HashMap and for the ***concurrency problem*** you need use `ConcurrentHashMap` to make sure `thread safe`,

You can use `TestBean.getHashMap()` to `get, put or remove` when you need:

```
class TestBean implements ServletContextAware {
    private static final HashMap hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    public static HashMap getHashMap() {
        return hashMap;
    }
}
```

`static` variable will exist all the time when your program is in runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the response.. solved the problem. Actually on production map object was getting replaced due to login of same user

Answer (score 1):

You should use application scope for your bean:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-application

You should add a user to a hashmap on every login and remove him on every logout.